# Accept null value on parent column in multipart relationship

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, schema, constraint, null

EDIT: I've come up with [one poor solution (below)](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/54495/10806) that requires some denormalization, but does avoid the risks of UDFs in `CHECK` constraints. I would appreciate your help if you have a better answer.

1. Each Category, except any 'built-in' Category, is only visible to
   its respective Owner.
2. Each item ("OwnedItem") must be assigned a Category that is visible
   to the item's Owner.

The challenge: since Owners can only see their own Categories and 'built-in' Categories, the data is invalid (for example) if one Owner's items are assigned a Category from another Owner, unless that Category is owned by no one.

Because of this, I would like to accept a null value (or a fixed value, e.g. -1) on one column of the parent in a multi-column relationship.

```
-- Categories have owners, or may be 'globally shared'
CREATE TABLE Category (
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    OwnerId int NULL,
    Title nvarchar(50) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT PK_Category PRIMARY KEY (Id ASC)
)

SET IDENTITY_INSERT Category ON
GO
INSERT INTO Category 
    (Id, OwnerId, Title)
VALUES
    (-1, NULL, 'Hidden'),
    (0, NULL, 'Default')
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT Category OFF
GO

-- Items have owners,
-- and must be assigned a category from the same owner,
-- or be assigned a global category
-- i.e. prevent assignment of items to another Owner's private Category
CREATE TABLE OwnedItem (
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CategoryId int NOT NULL,
    OwnerId int NOT NULL,
    Description varchar(50) NOT NULL
    CONSTRAINT PK_Ownedtem PRIMARY KEY (Id ASC)
)


ALTER TABLE OwnedItem
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_OwnedItemCategoryId
    FOREIGN KEY (CategoryId)
    REFERENCES Category (Id);

ALTER TABLE OwnedItem
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_CategoryOwnerOwnedItemOwner
    FOREIGN KEY (OwnerId)
    REFERENCES Category (OwnerId)

    -- How can I say:
    -- OR Category.OwnerId IS NULL

    ;
```

**How can I allow `OR Category.OwnerId IS NULL` immediately above?**

```
INSERT INTO OwnedItem
    (CategoryId, OwnerId, Description)
VALUES
    (-1, 23, 'Person23s hidden item')
-- SHOULD SUCCEED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just thought of a somewhat ugly way to enforce this. By replicating an additional copy of the key to the child table, I'm able to enforce *that* relationship to the parent, and then with that replicated information, perform more complex `CHECK` constraint logic on the child table.

1. Add a `CategoryOwnerId int NULL` column to `Item`.
2. Make the relationship on that rather than the `Item.OwnerId`.
3. Add a constraint to `Item`:

If null OwnerId is used in to represent a 'built-in' Category:

```
CategoryOwnerId NOT NULL OR CategoryId < 1
```

Or, with the same duplication of data but non-null 'built-in' Owner values:

```
CategoryOwnerId = OwnerId OR CategoryOwnerId = -1
```

Here's the change as-implemented:

```
DROP CONSTRAINT FK_OwnedItemCategoryId
DROP CONSTRAINT FK_CategoryOwnerOwnedItemOwner
GO

ALTER TABLE OwnedItem
ADD CategoryOwnerId INT NULL
GO

-- Prior to this schema change, all categories were system-wide/built-in
UPDATE OwnedItem
SET CategoryOwnerId = -1
GO

ALTER TABLE OwnedItem
ALTER COLUMN CategoryOwnerId INT NOT NULL
GO

ALTER TABLE OwnedItem
ADD CONSTRAINT FK_OwnedItemCategory
    FOREIGN KEY (CategoryId, OwnerId)
    REFERENCES Bin (Id, OwnerId);
GO

ALTER TABLE OwnedItem
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_OwnedItemCategoryBuiltinOrOwnerMatch
CHECK (OwnerId = CategoryOwnerId OR CategoryOwnerId = -1)
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Set [OwnerId] on OwnerID to allow nulls.
Put a null value record in your Category table:

```
INSERT INTO Category (OwnerId,Title) SELECT NULL,'blah??'
```

I also added  to your category table:

```
CONSTRAINT UC_OwnerID UNIQUE(OwnerID)
```

this is what I have working for you in SQL Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ac720/2.

Comment: I apologize, I assumed it would violate the constraint

Comment: yes, i think you also need owneditem.ownerid to allow nulls

Comment: that would violate my rules, though. if the item doesn't have an owner it won't be useful to the owner

Comment: I am trying out your solution right now

Comment: Yeah, as I suspected, null do not match the constraint as defined above. `There are no primary or candidate keys in the referenced table 'Category' that match the referencing column list in the foreign key`

Comment: ahh yes. OrderID on category has to be unique

Comment: I've got it working in the SQLFiddle link

Comment: Item was a typo for OwnedItem. I've edited my question.

Comment: Thanks for showing me sqlfiddle! Category.OwnerId is not supposed to be unique though. A person will definitely create multiple categories.

Comment: Hmm.. then maybe category,ownerid should be unique?  have fun. gtg

Comment: I don't think this train of thought is related to my question. Thank you though.